# How to apply Regular Expression to input using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, input

I have this code to force user to enter only numbers in input:

```
$("#Day").keyup(function()
{
 var test =new RegExp( "/\D/G");
 if(test.test($("#Day").val()))
     $("#Day").val(replace("/\D/G" , ""));
});
```

but it let me to type non-numbers and no error shown in console.

Comment: just to be clear, that code won't prevent someone from typing numbers, instead it will remove any numbers that are typed. (and the insertion point will change if the user is typing in the middle of a word, which would be very annoying)

Comment: @KevinB how can I prevent user to type non number?

Comment: Swap it around and only test the value when the submit happens or on blur, at which point you can display an appropriate error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked:

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/4RWBU/

I edited your original code in some ways. I change the event type from `keyup` to `keydown`. We can actually prevent the key pressed from display if we use `keydown` but I don't think that is possible to achieve with `keyup` (the key would have already been displayed).

```
$("#Day").keydown(function(e)
{
  var test = /[0-9]/; //regex
  var value = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode); //get the charcode and convert to char
  if (value.match(test)) { 
     return false; //dont display key if it is a number
  }       
});
```

Comment: @majidgeek It works perfectly in the fiddle. Check the fiddle

Comment: to let user to backspace, use this regex: `[0-9\b]`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without regex:

Add `type="number"` to your input and you should do fine.

But, if you want to support IE and HTML 4 users, you can also do this:

```
$("#Day").keyup(function () {
    var test = /\D/;
    if (test.test($(this).val())) {
        $("#Day").val($(this).val().replace(/\D/g, ""));
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4RWBU/1/)